# C++: Reuse operator+() in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Is there a way to reuse the `operator+(...)` method of the base class in a similar manner that the assignment operator `operator=(...)` is used in the example below?

IMPORTANT: I don't want to use abstract classes/virtual methods, I'm only curious about the example below for me to fully understand the "basic" usage of inheritance without going too much into polymorphism! The operator=() can be used successfully in this way in the example below, is it possible with the operator+()?

Base class:

```
class Vector
{
private:
  int _x;
  int _y;
protected:

  // constructors & destructors here

  Vector& operator=(const Vector& source){...}

  Vector operator+(const Vector& source) const{...}

};
```

Derived class:

```
class Position : public Vector
{
private:
  double _rho;
  double _phi;
public:

  // constructors & destructor here

  Position& operator=(const Position& source)
  {
    Vector::operator=(source); // slices source to its base-class part
    _rho = source._rho;
    _phi = source._phi;
    return *this;
  }

  Position operator+(const Position& source) const
  {
    /* 
    * HELP NEEDED HERE:
    * Some way of calling Vector::operator+() to avoid
    * code repetition and ensure consistency with the 
    * operator+ definition in the base class
    */
  }
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My initial comment, while a bit flippant, still holds true. With that said, I re-implemented your problem into something that will compile to demonstrate a solution.

First, your class (as shown) does not need an assignement operator overload. It also does not need a copy constructor, destructor, move constructor, or move assignment operator. This is because you aren't holding anything dynamic, therefore built-in shallow copies/assignments suffice.

With that said, I re-implemented your `operator+()` in a slightly more idiomatic fashion. If you can do `Derived + Derived`, people expect to be able to do `Derived += Derived` as well.

Because these are related to each other, it is possible to implement `operator+()` *in terms of* `operator+=()`. The only trick is taking advantage of pass-by-value.

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
 public:
  Base() = default;
  Base(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}

  // Assignment operator not required, Rule of 0

  Base& operator+=(const Base& rhs) {
    m_x += rhs.m_x;
    m_y += rhs.m_y;

    return *this;
  }

  friend Base operator+(Base lhs, const Base& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;

    return lhs;
  }

 // Needed to print a Derived object
 protected:
  int getX() const { return m_x; }
  int getY() const { return m_y; }

 private:
  int m_x = 0;
  int m_y = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Derived() = default;
  Derived(double rho, double phi) : Base(), m_rho(rho), m_phi(phi) {}
  Derived(int x, int y, double rho, double phi)
      : Base(x, y), m_rho(rho), m_phi(phi) {}

  Derived& operator+=(const Derived& other) {
    Base::operator+=(other);
    m_rho += other.m_rho;
    m_phi += other.m_phi;

    return *this;
  }

  friend Derived operator+(Derived lhs, const Derived& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;

    return lhs;
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sout, const Derived& rhs) {
    return sout << "x: " << rhs.getX() << "\ny: " << rhs.getY()
                << "\nrho: " << rhs.m_rho << "\nphi: " << rhs.m_phi;
  }

 private:
  double m_rho = 0.0;
  double m_phi = 0.0;
};

int main() {
  Derived d1;
  Derived d2(2, 2, 1.1, 1.1);

  Derived d3 = d1 + d2;
  Derived d4 = d2 + d3;
  std::cout << "\nd4:\n" << d4 << '\n';

  std::cout << "\nd3:\n" << d3 << '\n';

  std::cout << "\nd2:\n" << d2 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
d4:
x: 4
y: 4
rho: 2.2
phi: 2.2

d3:
x: 2
y: 2
rho: 1.1
phi: 1.1

d2:
x: 2
y: 2
rho: 1.1
phi: 1.1
```

You can see that I do "the same thing." In my `operator+=()`, I call the `Base` version first. Then I take care of the `Derived` members. This works because while `operator+=()` returns a reference, `operator+()` takes its `lhs` parameter by value, meaning it's a copy. The copy is altered by `operator+=()` and returned. Taking advantage of pass-by-value allowed me to use `operator+=()` without altering either of the original operands. So `operator+()` still behaves as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot sweenish. First on your comment, I am aware that copy constructors and assignment operators are not necessary, I did not want to overcomplicate using dynamic variables. I like your answer, and thanks a lot for the effort. However, is there a way of implementing the operator+ as a true member method and not a friend method? I guess my whole doubt was about how to use the member function on the derived class itself without it being passed as an argument. Is that possible at all?

Comment: Of the three ways two implement operator overloads, as a member function is the least recommended for `operator+()`. See the section 'Binary arithmetic operators' on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). Any solution that implements `operator+()` with the desired behavior as a member function is likely going to be less elegant than this one. Worth noting I didn't go through the trouble of implementing `operator<<()` for `Base` in the same way because I was not interested in printing `Base`es at all.

Comment: Good reference thanks. But nagging on around my question again (for learning purposes) how would I call the + operator from the base class as member method from the derived class? I know this is not correct but something like this->Base::operator+(...). If you call it just like operator+() it would end up being a recursive call. Do you know what I mean? Thanks!

Comment: You would make a copy of `this`, do the addition, and return the copy.