# C++: Calling protected base class constructor from derived class

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, derived-class

I'm experimenting with constructors/operators and access modifiers of classes that are NOT(!) abstract. Using public inheritance, I understand the protected modifier on base-class members/methods prevents access from instantiated base/derived objects, but allows access to the class itself and derived classes.

For the operator=() function I could leverage the base-class method, but why does this not work for the constructor? Is the only solution to implement the function in this way by making the constructor public?

Base class:

```
class Vector
{
private:
  int _x;
  int _y;
protected:
  Vector(int x, int y);
  Vector& operator=(const Vector& source);
// further constructors/operator overloads / getters & setters
};
```

Derived class:

```
class Position : public Vector
{
private:
  double _rho;
  double _phi;
public:
  // further constructors/operator overloads / getters & setters

  Position& Position::operator=(const Position& source)
  {
    Vector::operator=(source); // Here the calling of a protected method of the base class is allowed, which slices the input.
    _rho = source._rho;
    _phi = source._phi;
    return *this;
  }

  Position Position::operator+(const Position& source) const
  {
    // HELP HERE: the calling of protected methods (copy-constructor/getters of the base class is NOT allowed.
    Vector vec = Vector{*this} + Vector{source};
    return Position{vec.get_x(),vec.get_y()};
  }
};
```

Again, this is an experiment. The point of this exercise is not to make it work in general, but to make it work specifically leveraging the base class without changing the function signatures.

Thank you

Comment: [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/q38YT3), please provide a [mre]

Comment: That link isn't compiling. I think the issue is a lack of a public default constructor for `Vector`. Among other things. Like the lack of virtual destructor for `Vector`.

Comment: @sweenish The given link *does* compile - just doesn't link (no `main` provided).

Comment: I don't want to use any public constructors: I'm trying to define the operator+() in the following way:
Position Position::operator+(const Position& source) const
{
  Vector vec = Vector{*this} + Vector{source}; // can't acces the base constructor since protected
  return Position{vec.get_x(),vec.get_y()}; // can't access the get_ methods since protected
}

Comment: Possible issue is a pre-C++11 (?) compiler that doesn't like the `{...}` constructor call?

Comment: I suppose I used 'compile' in the sense that an executable wasn't generated. I rarely need to discuss the compilation process. Seems a poor practice to provide as proof. Especially since a `main()` would only need to be ~4 lines.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66700930/6119582) about this exact code, asked by someone I assume is a classmate. I understand that your question is constructor-specific, but a protected constructor is not your issue, the compiler doesn't treat it differently than any other protected function.

Comment: Hi sweenish, it was me who posted the other question. Following your last advice "You would make a copy of this, do the addition, and return the copy." this was my take. And it didn't work out. The only thing is that the "copy" is done using the base class copy constructor.

Comment: I edited the example to be more complete about what I'm trying to do. Thank you

Comment: So it is. I'm used to seeing multiple people post about the same assignment. You'll need to post relevant code and error messages in verbatim. You still don't need to provide an assignment operator in `Vector`. It seems like the code in question is exactly what's missing. The issue seems more like a lack of proper constructor/destructor setup for inheritance than the mechanics of inheritance themselves.

Comment: The moment I change the "protected" signature in the base class to "public", the error disappears. The error is: "error: calling a protected constructor of class 'Vector'
  Vector vec = Vector{*this} + Vector{source};"

Comment: Why do you want non-public constructors? It's usually only needed if you need to force the creation of an object through a factory method. Doesn't seem applicable here.

Comment: As i said in the first line, this is just an experiment for the sake of understanding. Why can I call the operator+() but not the constructor when both are protected base class methods?

Comment: A derived class can call protected members on its base class subobject, not on some arbitrary object of base class's type. You should be able to do something like `Vector vec = this->Vector::operator+(source));` (assuming `Vector` even provides `operator+`; none such is present in the code shown). That said, it's probably simpler to implement `operator+=` (it would be similar to `operator=`) on both classes, then implement `operator+` in terms of that, as in `{ Position result(*this); result += source; return result;}`